# How to iterate .extracttext in pdfplumber

Tags: list, pdf, iteration, text-extraction, pypdf

I am trying to build a tool to extract the text from each page of a PDF file. So far, only pdfplumber is returning readable text. Examples of pdfplumber (e.g. https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber) show the text being extracted *per* page. As such, I have done the following to capture multiple pages:

```
import pdfplumber

with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:

        p1 = pdf.pages[0]
        p2 = pdf.pages[1]
        p3 = pdf.pages[2]
    
        p1_text = p1.extract_text()
        p2_text = p2.extract_text()
        p3_text = p3.extract_text()
    
        print(p1_text, p2_text, p3_text)
```

My pdf has 17 pages. I want to know whether it is possible to iterate through a list (i.e. 0 - 16) in order to generate p1, p2, p3... p17 (the first block under the with statement).

I have generated the necessary list using:

```
file = '/Users/Guy/Coding/Crossref/sample.pdf'

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
pdf = PdfFileReader(open(file,'rb'))
total_pages = pdf.getNumPages()

total_pages_range = list(range(1, total_pages))
```

But can't seem to join the two together.

Any help would be much appreciated - just starting out with Python.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `pdfplumber.PDF` class has a `.pages` property which is a list containing one `pdfplumber.Page` instance per page loaded. So, if your PDF has `n` pages, you can iterate through all of them like

```py
import pdfplumber

with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:
    for page in pdf.pages:
        print(page.extract_text())
```